# Integrating Deso Identity into React Native App - retrieve user data from Deso Identity API call

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, authentication

I'm new to React Native and currently trying to integrate Deso Identity into my React Native App.

Question: How should I retrieve user data if I use WebView and what is the correct implementation to generate derived key?

Goal:

- Navigate to Deso Identity Page when clicking on a button from LogIn screen
- Receive derived key and all user response data after logging in

What I have tried:

- I'm currently trying to generate derive key by making a call to Deso's window API without using WebView
- I have tried using WebView with a DesoLogin.js component below but there's not much details from Deso's documentation and I was not able to retrieve response data after logging in

***DesoLogin.js***

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { WebView, WebViewNavigation } from 'react-native-webview';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import Home from '../screens/Home';

const DesoLogin = () =>{
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  // const webView = WebView();
  const [signIn, setSignIn] = useState(false)
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null)

  // function onMessage(data) {
  //   alert(data.nativeEvent.data);
  // }

  // const handleLogin = (e) => {
  //   const data = webView.getUrl(e);
  //   setUserProfile(data)
  // }

  const handleNavigationStateChange = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Home", {userProfile});
  }

  const onNavigationStateChange = e => {
    if (userProfile!==e.url) {
      console.log(e.url);
      setUserProfile(e.url);
      console.log(userProfile);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSignIn(true);
    if (userProfile) {
      handleNavigationStateChange();
    }
  },[userProfile])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: 'https://identity.deso.org/derive?callback=auth://derive'
        }}
        // onMessage={onMessage}s
        // injectedJavaScript={handleLogin}
        onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
        javaScriptEnabled
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
export default DesoLogin;
```

Error:

- I know that `windows.open()` doesn't work in react native like it does in web application

[Deso Mobile Integration Doc](https://docs.deso.org/for-developers/identity/mobile-integration)

[Window API-Callbacks section](https://docs.deso.org/for-developers/identity/window-api/basics)

***Login.js Screen code below***

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import axios from 'axios';
import DesoLogin from "../components/DesoLogin";
import DesoIdentity from "../libs/DesoIdentity";
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'

import { COLORS, FONTS, SIZES, SHADOWS, assets } from "../constants";
import { CircleButton, RectButton, DetailsDesc, DetailsBid, FocusedStatusBar } from "../components";

const LogIn = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [publicKey, setSetPublicKey] = useState(null)
  const [desoIdentity, setDesoIdentity] = useState(null)

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  useEffect(() => {
    axios('https://identity.deso.org/derive?callback=auth://derive')
    .then(response => {
      setSetPublicKey(response.accessSignature)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error Fetching data", error);
      setError(error);
      throw error;
    })
  } , [])

  const handleSignUp = () => {
    return 0;
  }

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    setSetPublicKey(publicKey);
    setLoggedIn(true);
  }
  const handleLogout = () => {
    setSetPublicKey(null);
    setLoggedIn(false);
  }

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.container}
      behavior="padding"
    >
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
          style={styles.input}
          secureTextEntry
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={handleLogin}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          // onPress={handleSignUp}
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}

export default LogIn;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: '80%'
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    width: '60%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#0782F9',
    width: '100%',
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonOutline: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    marginTop: 5,
    borderColor: '#0782F9',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: COLORS.white,
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  buttonOutlineText: {
    color: '#0782F9',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
})
```